# Method of characteristics - eliminating variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am trying to follow a guide for the [method of characteristics](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Epete/pde/characteristics.pdf); quoting the first example:

> We use the method of characteristics to solve the problem
>
> $ 2u_x - u_y = 0, \;\; u(x, 0) = f(x) $
>
> (...) we can easily solve [the characteristic equations] to get:
>
> $x = 2s + x_0 \;\;\; y= -s + y_0 \;\;\; u = u_0$

Up to here I have no problem. However, the guide then substitutes in the initial condition and says this:

> we now eliminate $x_0$ and $s$ to find that:
>
> $ y = -s \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; u = f(x_0) = f(x - 2s) = f(x + 2y)$

My question is: where did $y_0$ and $u_0$ go?

Comment: More simply, the method shows that for every $(x_0,y_0,s)$, $$u(x_0+2s,y_0-s)=u(x_0,y_0).$$ For every $(x,y)$, choosing $(x_0,y_0,s)=(x+2y,0,-y)$ above, one gets $$u(x,y)=u(x+2y,0).$$ Rename $u(\ ,0)$ as $f$ and you are done.

Comment: @Did I.. don't quite follow. How does the method show that?

Comment: First line simply rephrases the fact that "$u$ remains constant on the curve $(x(s),y(s))$", for $x(s)=2s+x_0$, $y(s)=-s+y_0$, that is, that $u(x(s),y(s))=u(x(0),y(0))$ for every $s$. Second line is self-explanatory. What remains?

Comment: @Did I think there's some deep background here that I've missed - "$u$ remains constant on the curve $(x(s), y(s))$" isn't a fact that I recognise. Where does it come from?

Comment: Lines 3-5 of the text you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have characteristics given as functions $x(s)$ and $y(s)$ which depend on parameter $s$:

\begin{align}
x = x(s) &= x_0 + 2s && \implies& x_0 &= x - 2s   \label{1}\tag{1}
\\ 
y = y(s) &= y_0 - s  && \implies& y_0 &= y + s   \label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

The initial condition $u\left(x_0, 0\right) = f\left(x_0\right)$ is given for $y_0=0$, so in equation $\eqref{2}$ we set $y_0$ to be equal  $0$:

$$0 = y_0 = y + s \qquad\;\implies \quad\bbox[5pt, border: 1.5pt solid #DD0712]{y = -s^{\,\!}}  \label{3}\tag{3}$$

But then we can write general solutions as 
$$
u\left(x_0, y_0\right) = u\left(x_0, 0\right) = f\left(x_0\right) = f\left(x-2s\right) \overset{\eqref{3}}{=} f\left(x+2s\right)
$$

---

Now, one can ask why do we say that $u\left(x_0, y_0\right)$ is the general solution?
Well, if you recall the definition of characteristics, which are the

> *$\;\big(\cdots\big)\;$ parametric curves along which solution $u\left(x, y\right)$ remains **constant**,*

you will see that $u\left(x, y\right) = u\left(x_0, y_0\right)$ as long as $(x,y)$ and $\left(x_0,y_0\right)$ lie on the same curve $\eqref{1}$–$\eqref{2}$.
Then we ***choose*** $y_0$ to be equal $0$ in order to incorporate initial condition $u(x,0) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equations are :
$$\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{du}{0}$$
which leads to the equations of chararacteristics :
$$\begin{cases}u=c_1\\x+2y=c_2 \end{cases}$$
The general solution on implicit form with is :
$$\Phi\left(u\:,\:x+2y\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any derivable function of two variables.

This is equivalent to :
$$u=F(x+2y)$$
where $F$ is any derivable function.

The bounding condition leads to :
$$u(x,0)=f(x)=F(x+0)=F(x)$$
Hense $F=f$ is now determined and the solution is :
$$u(x,y)=F(x+2y)=f(x+2y)$$